# Retrofit - Get Raw non JSON Array

Tags: android, json, http, retrofit

I am using Retrofit2 for the first time and have a problem to get a simple Array in non JSON format.

Error:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 path $[0]`

This means its not an JSON Object since it does not start with "{"

I tried adding the **ScalarsConverter** but it doesent seems to work.

Api: https://chasing-coins.com/api/v1/coins

Interface:

```
public interface Retro_coins {
    @GET("api/v1/coins")
    Call<List<Coinlist>> getCoinlist();
}
```

Class:

```
public class Coinlist {
    private List coinlist;

    public List getCoinlist() {
        return coinlist;
    }
        }
```

Retrofit initialization and call:

```
String API_BASE_URL = "https://chasing-coins.com/";

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                ;
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        Retro_coins client =  retrofit.create(Retro_coins.class);



// Fetch list
        Call<List<Coinlist>> call =
                client.getCoinlist();

// Execute the call asynchronously. Get a positive or negative callback.
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Coinlist>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Coinlist>> call, Response<List<Coinlist>> response) {
                // The network call was a success and we got a response
                Log.w("Yes", response.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Coinlist>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.w("no", t.toString());

            }
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its because your object is wrong. What you are fetching is simply a list of Strings

Comment: If you not using JSON you dont need     addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) use the format you expect on your format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `private List coinlist;`, Gson expects the object to be

```
{  
   "coinlist":"[]"
}
```

where as what you are providing is just

```
["String","String","String"]
```

furthermore when you use `Call<List<Coinlist>>` you are expecting the data to be

```
[  
   {  
      "coinlist":"[]"
   }
]
```

Just change your call from `Call<List<Coinlist>>` to `Call<List<String>>`. That should fix your problem. Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Great answer and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your request Returning String. So you need to Change the Response to String or Need to change your request Call to String.